# How to update row that is selected in original dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am able to select the a row I want to update using this code:

```
df1.loc[df1.MemberID.isin(df2.Email)]
```

Within `df1` there is a `flag` field I want to change to `TRUE`.

How do I update the row that has been selected in `df1` without deleting any of the other rows in `df1`?

Comment: Are you looking for `df1['flag'] = df1.MemberID.isin(df2.Email)`?

Comment: Thats it! i will take the answer, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df1['flag'] = df1.MemberID.isin(df2.Email)
```

`df1.MemberID.isin(df2.Email)` returns a Boolean series which you can use to fill your column `flag`.

Comment: I didnt know that you could use it to fill the flag. thank you once again